# Why doesn't code contract display message?

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I have the following as the first line in a method:

```
Contract.Requires(param1 != null, "param1 can't be null");
```

When param1 comes in null, nothing happens and code below the contract continues to execute.  Is something else needed for the message to display?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Contract class docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.aspx):

> You must use a binary rewriter to insert run-time enforcement of contracts. Otherwise, contracts such as the Contract.Ensures method can only be tested statically and will not throw exceptions during run time if a contract is violated. You can download the binary rewriter CCRewrite from Code Contracts on the MSDN DevLabs Web site. CCRewrite comes with a Visual Studio add-in that enables you to activate run-time contract enforcement from the project Properties page. The binary rewriter and the Visual Studio add-in do not ship with Visual Studio 2010 or the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the inspection in your project properties (Project in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Code Contracts and then define your settings for static check and runtime check.

The unchecked calls will be underlined with purple squiggles and you get hints in your Log window.